# Return multiple row without the use of mysqlnd

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I dont have mysqlnd available, so i implemented a helper function to do the job:

public function bind_array($stmt, &$row) {

```
    $md = $stmt->result_metadata();

        var_dump($md);
    $params = array();

    while($field = $md->fetch_field()) 
    {
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}
```

The trouble is, that i also need it to be able to return multiple rows. As of now it can only return a single row.

Thanks....

EDIT: What im aiming for is getting the same result as when calling mysqli fetch_assoc, which is not available for me, as i dont have mysqlnd... The array will afterwards be json_encoded ..

Comment: Did you try to use search? You are apparently not the first one with such a problem.

Comment: i did .. but i did not find a suitable answer .. or i might not have noticed what i really need to do the job

Comment: can't you, by chance, use PDO?

Comment: i could .. but that would force me to change all of my code

Comment: that would be a good change which will return a hundredfold

Comment: THUMBS up for your suggention about switching to PDO .. progress well on the way, and it turns out to be just as easy as working with mysqlnd .. would like to accept your answer, but its not marked as an answer and maybe id didnt answer my initial question .. but its up to you :)

Comment: in fact, PDO is WAY easier than mysqli with mysqlnd.

Comment: if you post some usual cases of your SQL queries, I'll post the proper code for handling them. Just to show you how it can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, PDO is WAY easier than mysqli with mysqlnd.

You can try [my wrapper for PDO which can make it even better than original class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper/blob/master/bestpdo.php) - it's incredible simple in use, combining simplicity of old mysql functions with power and safety of prepared statements.

Say, to get your multiple results you wull need **one single line of code**, opposite to several screens in case of mysqli or half-dozen when using old mysql functions:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT return, fields  FROM table WHERE search_field = ?';
$data = DB:prepare($sql)->execute([$search_val])->fetchAll();
```

now $data contains the desired result you can iterate over

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
     echo $row['fields'];
}
```

Just define four constants with your DB credentials somewhere and then you'll be able to use database anywhere in your code, just like with old mysql ext used to be.