# How does mysql_fetch_array($result_type=MYSQL_BOTH) return both associative and numeric indices?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, it states that "By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices."  But it is my understanding that php arrays can either be associative or numeric, not both.  You could obviously create an associative array that contains the numeric indices as well, as keys, but that would double the array count.  So how do they do this?  Have they made a special exception for this one function?  Is what it returns not actually a conventional array but their own special array just for this purpose?  Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: "You could obviously create an associative array that contains the numeric indices as well, as keys, but that would double the array count." Yep, that's it. Nothing magic to it.

Comment: Why worry about how mysql_* functions work anyway? The fact that you're even asking this question shows that you don't really have a strong grasp on PHP yet, so I'm assuming you're starting a relatively new project. These functions have been removed from the latest PHP and deprecated since version 5.5. Use PDO or mysqli instead. See the big red warning box at the top of the page you linked?

Comment: It's precisely because I'm trying to convert to mysqli that I am asking this question.  I am trying to convert a mysql_fetch_array wrapper function so that it can be used on the results of prepared statements, but I cannot just use mysqli_fetch_array, because this requires a mysqli_result instance as an argument, and I can't use mysqli_get_result because I don't have mysqlnd installed, and installing mysqlnd is out of the question.  My project is the opposite of new.  I can't use PDO because I am converting mysql wrappers, so I am trying to recreate the exact equivalent functions.

Comment: Some stuff for you to munch on: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#113398 http://stackoverflow.com/a/22552607/811240 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752815/mysqli-get-result-alternative

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP Documentation on Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) a PHP array is "Actually an ordered map", and can be both associative and numeric. Using `MYSQL_BOTH` uses associative and numeric keys in the same array.